# Trying to make changes on two different child forms from main form using Custom Events

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, windows

I have an application with three forms.

I want to be able to update the listview control when a new object is being created in a separate form when all three of them are displayed.

**MainForm** - Contains a List collection instantiated inside, two buttons where CarForm and ListViewCarForm are instantiated.

```
public static List<Cars> listOfCars = new List<Cars>();

public List<Cars> CarList
{
   get { return listOfCars; }
   set { listOfCars = value; }
}

private void displayListViewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListViewCarForm lvcf = new ListViewCarForm();
   lvcf.Show();
}

private void newCarFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CarForm cf = new CarForm();
   cf.Show();

   //Adds new item created to listOfItems 
   cf.ObjectCreatedToList += ObjectCreatedToListCollectionHandler;
}
```

**CarForm** - Contains controls for the user to enter values, those values are stored inside a class member variable that is created as an object and is then added inside the List Collection in the MainForm

```
public EventHandler ObjectCreatedToList;

//Class Property that assigns values to member variables
public Cars Info
{
   get
   {
       //Instantiates new Cars class, assigns member variables to control values and returns new Cars object
   }
   set
   {
       //set control values to Cars member variables
   }  
}

private void addCarToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(ObjectCreatedToList != null)
   {
       ObjectCreatedToList(this, new EventArgs());
   }
   //Some Validation here to prevent control values to reset

   //If all control values are entered, this will clear the controls
   Info = new Cars();
}
```

**ListViewForm** - Contains a ListView where when items are being added into the List Collection in CarForm, it should also be added to the listview control

The problem I am having is when all three forms are opened, the listview control inside the ListViewForm should be updated as new objects are being created by the CarForm and added inside the List Collection inside the MainForm.

Since the two forms are being instantiated inside a different button in the MainForm, I can't seem to figure out how to add the items inside the listview control without it not hitting the method or giving me an error.

*This is my first time working with Windows Application Forms

Comment: You should name your forms.

Comment: They are in my real code.

Comment: Looking at the “SecondForm” code section, why are you creating a NEW `Form1`? The `Form1` created in that part of the code is never displayed (Show()). Therefore in that event, it appears you create the new form1 then add some info to its `CarList`… but that is it…. Once, you leave the `enterCarToListToolStripButton_Click` event… the `Form1` `mainForm` created in that event will no longer exist.

Comment: I don't need to show the MainForm since it's already displayed? I just needed to instantiate it to access the list to add the new item... is that wrong practice?

Comment: The line of code: `Form1 mainForm = new Form1();`.... creates a NEW `Form1`. You may well have ANOTHER form1 already displayed, unfortunately the line of code that follows: `mainForm.CarList.Add(Info);` is going to reference the `mainForm` you just created, as I stated in my last comment... after exiting this portion of code... the newly created `mainForm` will no longer exist.

Comment: Should it be Form1 mainForm = sender as Form1; then?

Comment: Since the `mainform` already exist and is already displayed, it appears you need access to the `mainForms`’s `CarList` variable. There are numerous ways to achieve this. One possible solution is to pass this variable to `Form2` when you create it… something like: `Form2 controlsForm = new Form2(CarList);`.

Comment: I'll be frank, that completely lost me.

Comment: You should do some searching on how to pass information between parent and child forms. I will try and supply a small answer.

Answer (score 0):

To keep this simple, one solution is to pass the variable you need to the child form. Example: assuming the main form contains a `ListBox` of items and a button to open a `Controlsform`, then, when the user clicks the “Open Control Form” button… the `ControlsForm` is open, it has a text box and a button. When the user types something into the text box and then clicks the “Add to Parent List” button, the text in the text box should be added to the parent form’s `ListBox` items. You can pass the `ListBox` or `List<Car>` or anything you need to the child form. Hope this makes sense.

[image]

The `MainForm` has a `ListBox` and a button. The `ListBox` on the form is named `Form1ListBoxControl`. When the user clicks the “Open Control Form” button, the variable `Form1ListBoxControl` is passed to the newly created `ControlsForm` then the `ControlsForm` is shown…As above

**Main form** “Open Control Form” button click event…

```
private void btnOpenControlsForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ControlsForm controlsForm = new ControlsForm(Form1ListBoxControl);
  controlsForm.Show();
}
```

**ControlsForm...**

To use the passed `Form1ListBoxControl` variable in the `ControlsForm` we need to make a global `ListBox` variable so the other methods in the form can use the parents `ListBox`…

```
ListBox parentListBox;
```

In addition, we need to create a new "Constructor” for the `ControlsForm` to accept a `ListBox` parameter and use this parameter as the global variable defined above.…

```
public ControlsForm(ListBox passedParentListBox) {
  InitializeComponent();
  parentListBox = passedParentListBox;
}
```

Finally the button event in the `ControlsForm` to add new items to the parents `ListBox`…

```
private void btnAddToParentList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  parentListBox.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: What if you're working with more than two forms and are passing more than one data? You just create new constructors each time?

Comment: In the above Case... yes. There are other ways to do this.