# Multi form Projects in c# - Displaying multiple windows

Tags: c#, winforms

My main form is this

[image]

Now my problem occurs when I click Add -> Student, which is meant to bring up a new window that, instead it does this
[image]

So as you can see it opens the new form inside the same window. It didn't use to do this, then I made the main form an `MdiContainer` and set it as the `MdiParent` of the second form.

Is there a property I can change to make this new form pop up in a new window? Becuase I need to leave the MdiContainer property as True so that I can take data from `Form2` and use it in `Form1`

Please let me know any other information you may need to help me fix this issue, as I'm not sure what caused it so I don't know what to change in order to fix it or even where I'm meant to be looking

Comment: You should not be setting `MdiContainer` to `true` and you do not need it to [pass data to another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204773/).

Comment: I agree with Dour High Arch… It is unclear, why you would use MDI in this situation. Not only does it appear unnecessary, but enormously complicates the UI and work for you. Using two separate forms appears to be not only more user friendly, but also less work on your part to manage the form. Is there some reason you must use an MDI implementation?

Comment: No, no reason why, I just though it was needed to add new data to a list in `Form1` that was gathered from `Form2`, how do I do this without Mdi?

Comment: Depending on what you are passing back and forth will most likely dictate how you would implement this data passing. There a numerous ways to do this, a simple way would be to pass the needed info in the constructor of the child form. [Simple data passing using forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418386/trying-to-make-changes-on-two-different-forms-from-another-form-using-custom-eve/44421638#44421638)

Comment: Bear in mind the link is a very simplistic example and it appears you may need to pass a `Student` “Class”. Another option is to create public getters and setters in the main form for variables you want the child form to update. Try something and if it does not work, post back here.

Comment: MDI has been obsolete for a very long time, and should not be used in new applications.

Comment: It is duely noted that I should not be using MDI, you can stop reminding me now thank you though. I have removed MDI, now just working on a new method to pass data between forms

Answer (score -1):

you need to hide form enroll 
when you open add window `add.show()`

you need to hide enroll form `enroll.hide()`